# Is it correct to say or not? How to make question sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Could you please explain to me whether it is correct to say "The book used to be called differently" or it is better to say "The book was called differently"? If the first one is correct then how to make a question sentence from it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: _Used to be_ and _was_ are both OK, but it would be much more natural to say "The book used to have a different title".

Answer (score -1):

both of them are correct.
for making a question sentence there are two way:

> 1- Did the book use to be called differently?
>   2- Used the book to be called differently?